# Windows phone: Changing font size within the same string

Tags: c#, css, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a string property that will be displayed as a content in the tile of my application. I want to do the following thing: In the first 'row' of this string I want to display some basic information in the default font size but in the second 'row' of this string I want to display 2 values with a bigger font size... Still this string property is one... Is there any way of implementing this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`<RichTextBox` is somewhat hard to deal with in WP8 IMHO.  But you can do it pretty easy with just a `<TextBlock>` and a **Converter**.

Basically use the Run with the same string and pass that to your Converter which returns the SubString that you want to format (in your case your string of chars for your row number).

```XAML
<!-- MyString is your Property, MyConverter is your Converter you programmed, ConverterParamter is the row_number that you want to pass to MyConver -->
<TextBlock x:Name="tb">
    <Run FontSize="12" Text="{Binding MyString, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"/>
    <Run FontSize="24" Text="{Binding MyString, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>                
</TextBlock>
```

---

```C#
// sample Converter of what you want to do
using System.Windows.Data;
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string return_string = "";
        int rowid = (int) parameter;
        switch (rowid)
        {
            case 0:
                return_string = "sub_string_row_0"; // calculate the substring for row 0
                break;
            case 1:
                return_string = "sub_string_row_1"; // calculate the substring for row 1
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }    
        return return_string;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Remember to define your Converter in your Resources like so

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converter:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Where `<conveter:>` is

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:YOUR_NAMESPACE_OF_YOUR_PROGRAM">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... I think I understand the way you suggest me but I am sticking with the part of getting the text from the XAML object and pass it to a string in C#... Will I get the text of the `tb` textblock?

Comment: @AlexAllafi Oh you don't set the text of the TB directly.  I bind the value of it to a property named "MyString".  Look up a sample tutorial on Databinding (it is pretty simple) if you want an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier if you create 3 additional properties that will just each return part of your "main" string.

For example:

```
public string PartOne { get { return myString.SubString(0, 3); }}
```